# Collapse-able menu controlled by an external button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a collapse-able menu. Is it possible to show `Collapsible Group Item #1` when button `#externalBtn` is clicked?

```
    <div class="panel-group" id="panel-219487">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                 <a class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#panel-219487" href="#panel-element-702909">Collapsible Group Item #1</a>
            </div>
            <div id="panel-element-702909" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                 <a class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#panel-219487" href="#panel-element-81966">Collapsible Group Item #2</a>
            </div>
            <div id="panel-element-81966" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class='myBtns' id='externalBtn' onclick='Ty()'><img src='img/profile.png'/></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use below code. it's working fine.

```
 $('#externalBtn').click(function (e) {
    $(".panel-collapse").collapse('hide');
    $('#panel-element-702909').collapse('show')
});
```

see working example on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/DSGxz/

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be use `.toggle` however this will also reverses the action when you click on `#externalBtn` again.

```
$('#externalBtn').click(function () {
    $(".panel-collapse").toggle();
    $('#panel-element-702909').toggle();
});
```